# Load grub menu when running ubuntu 22.04 LTS on VMware workstation 16 player

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

How to load grub menu while booting ubuntu 22.04 LTS on VMware workstation 16 player to get back sudo access to the user  Also how to boot ubuntu on VMware ?

Answer (score 0):

As per: [How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)

Shortly after you click "PLAY" VM:

Menu will appear if you press and hold **Shift** during loading Grub, if you boot using BIOS. When your system boots using UEFI, press **Esc**.